# Unable to display UILabel in multiple lines in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel, multiline

I have a tableView cell with two labels as shown below. The constraints for these labels can be seen in the images.

[image]
[image]

For each label, I have set the **number of lines** to **0** and the **line break** option to **Word Wrap**. However, when the tableView loads, the texts get shown in a single line as below.

[image]

What might be causing this issue?

Comment: Do you have a height constraint for the label?

Comment: I do not have height constraints for the labels.

Comment: Please make a screenshot of all constraints (look at the right tab on Xcode) for this particular view and add it to the question

Comment: You should add height constraints with 749 priority each of them.

Comment: You can set the tableview cell height to autodimension

Comment: Did ur issue solve ??

Answer (score 2):

It might have happened because it takes the custom height of the `UITableViewCell`

Please set `estimatedRowHeight` and `rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

It will solve your problem

Thank you!!!

Comment: Looks like the OP is using a storyboard, so worth noting that this can also be done by making sure that **Row Height** and **Estimate** are set to **Automatic**